# Orthogonality and 2-filtered 2-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $C$ be a category. It is well known that $C$ is $\omega$-filtered if and only if it is weakly right orthogonal to every $A\to A^\rhd$, where $A^\rhd$ is the right cone of a finite category $A$.

This is neat: an $\infty$-category is $\omega$-filtered if the same condition holds for all $\omega$-small $\infty$-categories. A similar condition defines $\kappa$-filtered categories for higher ordinals.

What about 2-categories? There is a notion of being 2-filtered: http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/2filtered.pdf but I fail to see an obvious reason why this shall be an orthogonality request with respect to a similar class, and I don't know how to find an explicit description of the class $\cal H$ to which 2-filtered 2-categories are injective.

Comment: It seems to me that all the condition of the definition are of the form "given some diagram in the category, it can be extended into", which is exactly an orthogonality condition. In fact it is always extending some finite diagram by adding a right pseudo-cone. Am I missing something ?

Comment: No, I'm confident this is true, but I'm unable to find an explicit description of the category, or family of categories, such that $\{\text{2filtered}\} = \mathcal H^\perp$; maybe I'm not staring hard enough!

Comment: What I mean't is that each axiom of the definition is explicitly stated as a lifting condition against a given freely generated $2$-category, so you get a very natural (finite) choice for $\mathcal{H}$. In fact unless I missed one, they are all of the form $A \rightarrow A^\rhd$ for $A$ a finite $2$-category and $A^\rhd$ obtained from $A$ by adding a pseudo terminal object. But maybe what you want is a "bigger" more uniform and natural choice for $\mathcal{H}$, like "all the map $A \rightarrow A^\rhd$" for $A$ a finite a 2-category" ?

Comment: BTW, you seem to be mixing up orthogonality and injectivity a bit.  Here we are talking about injectivity.  (Perhaps this is what you mean by "weakly right orthogonal"?)

Comment: If you want the statement that one can take "any finite category" instead of justs the specific ones in the paper it should be possible to deduce it from proposition 3.1.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09429.pdf for the right choice of $\Sigma$. I assume a version of this without $\Sigma$ appeared somewhere before, but I'm very familiar with the topic.